# How to properly install Go Language in Ubuntu?

Tags: software-installation, golang

I'm trying follow [these instructions](http://www.howtogeek.com/196635/an-official-google-drive-for-linux-is-here-sort-of-maybe-this-is-all-well-ever-get/) to install Drive but I can't get `Go` to work properly.

I keep getting the error:

`go tool: no such tool "6g"`

When I try to use `go get [url]`. I also get this error when trying to run a hello world script (to check that Go had installed correctly).

I've tried installing the individual programs [recommended in this post](http://devhead.ru/read/correct-gopath-and-goroot-in-ubuntu) (golang-go.tools gccgo-go) regarding fixing this error but the problem persists.

How can I get the `6g` tool?

Here are the results of `go env`:

```
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN=""
GOCHAR="6"
GOEXE=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="linux"
GOOS="linux"
GOPATH="/home/user/go"
GORACE=""
GOROOT="/usr/share/go"
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/share/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64"
TERM="dumb"
CC="gcc"
GOGCCFLAGS="-g -O2 -fPIC -m64 -pthread"
CXX="g++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
```

Comment: did you set GOPATH and GOROOT?

Comment: Yes, first I was getting an error regarding the GOPATH. I used [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21001387/how-do-i-set-the-gopath-environment-variable-on-ubuntu-what-file-must-i-edit) SO question to find the solution which then brought me to this next error that I can't fix.

Comment: Do you need the latest version of Go? It's far easier to install Go from the archive - `sudo apt-get install golang`.

Comment: @NathanOsman I don't think so, I just need to be able to compile a program that was written in Go (last September). I ran `sudo apt-get install golang` but it returned 0 to upgrade, newly install, 62 not to upgrade and I'm still unable to use `go get` and `go run`. Do I need to force apt-get to overwrite my current version of Go?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem is your `GOROOT`. It should be set to `/usr/lib/go` (**not** `/usr/share/go`).

```
export GOROOT=/usr/lib/go
```

Answer (score 2):

### Installation

1. Update.

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   ```
2. Install Go language.

   ```
   sudo apt-get install golang
   ```
3. Set GOPATH to your home folder. After this action, you can use command `echo $GOPATH` to check the go path location.

   ```
   export GOPATH=$HOME/gopath
   ```
4. For the GOPATH, it is not required to define it. But you can still define it.

   ```
   # Get the go installation root path.
   go env GOROOT

   # Set the result of `go env GOROOT` to system variable GOROOT.
   # In this example, the result of `go env GOROOT` is `/usr/lib/go-1.6`
   export GOROOT=/usr/lib/go-1.6
   ```

### Checking Go Environment Variables

1. Use command `go env` and you will get:

   ```
   GOARCH="amd64"
   GOBIN=""
   GOEXE=""
   GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
   GOHOSTOS="linux"
   GOOS="linux"
   GOPATH="/home/casper/gopath"
   GORACE=""
   GOROOT="/usr/lib/go-1.6"
   GOTOOLDIR="/usr/lib/go-1.6/pkg/tool/linux_amd64"
   GO15VENDOREXPERIMENT="1"
   CC="gcc"
   GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -pthread -fmessage-length=0"
   CXX="g++"
   CGO_ENABLED="1"
   ```
2. Now you can see that:

   a. `GOPATH` is in `/home/casper/gopath`.

   b. `GOROOT` is in `/usr/lib/go-1.6`.

### References

- Install package golang
  https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Ubuntu
- You don’t need to set GOROOT, really
  http://dave.cheney.net/2013/06/14/you-dont-need-to-set-goroot-really
- Getting Started - The Go Programming Language
  https://golang.org/doc/install

Comment: `golang` package is officially in repository, why should I add a PPA, where these PPAs are known for issues?