# How to install and use pup from golang?

Tags: software-installation, scripts, snap, html, golang

I installed `go` through snap; now how do I invoke `pup`?

```
thufir@dur:~/pup$ 
thufir@dur:~/pup$ go get github.com/ericchiang/pup
thufir@dur:~/pup$ 
thufir@dur:~/pup$ curl "skynet.be/nieuws-sport/weer/mijn-weer?cityId=6450" | pup 'div.tides' >out.html
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
Command 'pup' not found, but there are 17 similar ones.

100   268  100   268    0     0    740      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   740
(23) Failed writing body
thufir@dur:~/pup$ 
thufir@dur:~/pup$ cat out.html 
thufir@dur:~/pup$ 
thufir@dur:~/pup$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.10
Release:    18.10
Codename:   cosmic
thufir@dur:~/pup$
```

Not sure that it's installed or not, actually:

```
thufir@dur:~/pup$ 
thufir@dur:~/pup$ go list
can't load package: package .: no Go files in /home/thufir/pup
thufir@dur:~/pup$ 
thufir@dur:~/pup$ go version
go version go1.11.4 linux/amd64
thufir@dur:~/pup$
```

It looks [interesting](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/492116/17056) in and of itself.  My [info](https://askubuntu.com/q/593957/45156) is:

```
thufir@dur:~/pup$ 
thufir@dur:~/pup$ go env
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN=""
GOCACHE="/home/thufir/.cache/go-build"
GOEXE=""
GOFLAGS=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="linux"
GOOS="linux"
GOPATH="/home/thufir/go"
GOPROXY=""
GORACE=""
GOROOT="/snap/go/3095"
GOTMPDIR=""
GOTOOLDIR="/snap/go/3095/pkg/tool/linux_amd64"
GCCGO="gccgo"
CC="gcc"
CXX="g++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
GOMOD=""
CGO_CFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_CPPFLAGS=""
CGO_CXXFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_FFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_LDFLAGS="-g -O2"
PKG_CONFIG="pkg-config"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -pthread -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=/tmp/go-build303962824=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches"
thufir@dur:~/pup$
```

I tried running `pup` from the `~/go/` but got the same result.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue trying to install pup.

Steps you have to follow:

1. `export GOROOT=/usr/bin/go` (path found running `whereis go`)
2. Go to your GOPATH:

   `cd /home/thufir/go`
   There you will find a **bin** folder and inside the **pup** binary
3. Copy binary pup to /usr/bin/

   `sudo cp pup /usr/bin`
4. Check if pup is correctly installed

   `pup --version`

   I hope it works.

Comment: Worked on Fedora 35, ignoring the first step.